# Postman. JS. Как добавить символ в переменную

Tags: javascript, переменные, postman

Доброе утро. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Делаю post запрос в postman, получаю подобный json ответ:

```
{
    "paramsId": "AP100036UFCOAGID965RH6SU4LFORVH0",
    "qrcId": "AS1R005T99N14LD49CGBMKOQE9NBS1BG",
    "amount": 25000,
    "currency": "RUB",
    "paymentPurpose": "testing cash register qrc"
}
```

Из этого ответа мне нужно забрать в переменную значение

```
"amount": 25000
```

Во вкладке tests у меня

```
let QRresponse = pm.response.json();
console.log(QRresponse.amount);
pm.environment.set("Amount", QRresponse.amount);
```

Ответ в консоли

```
POST https://host/api/qrcash/v1/cash-register-qrc/AS1R0057CNJG6B5O82JQOVJKIV6V0IQC/params
200
45 ms
 
25000
```

Ребят подскажите как вытащить это значение в переменную так, что бы перед двумя последними символами стояла точка (пример: 250.00 или 9999.99)

Answer (score 0):

Для себя нашел такое решение:

```
let QRresponse = pm.response.json();
let amount = (QRresponse.amount / 100).toFixed(2)
console.log(amount);
pm.environment.set("Amount", amount);
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить число на экспоненту (К примеру `1e+42`) или на цифру (к примеру `2`). Что-то явно пойдёт не так...

Answer (score 0):

Вставьте этот код после `let QRresponse = pm.response.json();`:

```
let num = QRresponse.amount.toLocaleString().replace(/,/g, '')
let amoutToSet = num.slice(0, num.length-2) + (num.length > 3 ? '' : '.') + num.slice(num.length-2);
pm.environment.set("Amount", amoutToSet);
```